# Get response from a webview in android

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am using a payment gateway(Voguepay) where the request URL generates a response URL I want to redirect to that URL in webview

my code for the webview

```
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webveiw);
        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());


        // REMOTE RESOURCE
         mWebView.loadUrl("https://voguepay.com/?p=linkToken&v_merchant_id=demo&\n" +
                 " memo=Payment for laptop&total=1000&merchant_ref=ref123&\n" +
                 " notify_url=https://example.com/notification.php&\n" +
                 " success_url=https://example.com/success.php&\n" +
                 " fail_url=https://example.com/fail.php&developer_code=ddd&cur=NGN");
}
```

the request URL loads successfully and display this
[image: what it displays when it load url]

I want to redirect the webview to load the link in the image above

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your problem correctly you could use this code :

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
    // do your handling codes here, which url is the requested url
    // probably you need to open that url rather than redirect:
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return false; // then it is not handled by default action
}
});
```